# Setting elasticsearch properties in spark-submit

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I'm trying to launch Spark jobs that use Elastic Search input via command line using spark-submit as described in http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html

I'm setting the properties in a file, but when launching spark-submit it gives the following warnings:

```
~/spark-1.0.1-bin-hadoop1/bin/spark-submit --class Main --properties-file spark.conf SparkES.jar

Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: es.resource=myresource
Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: es.nodes=mynode
Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: es.query=myquery
...
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed
```

My config file looks like (with correct values):

```
es.nodes      nodeip:port
es.resource   index/type
es.query      query
```

Setting the properties in the **Configuration** object in the code works, but I need to avoid this workaround.

Is there a way to set those properties via command line?

Comment: can you add your spark.conf file to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you resolved your issue (if so, how?), but I found this solution:

```
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark

EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "spark/docs", Map("es.nodes" -> "10.0.5.151"))
```

Bye

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a config file to spark-submit, it only loads configs that start with 'spark.'

So, in my config I simply use

```
spark.es.nodes <es-ip>
```

and in the code itself I have to do

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("es.nodes", conf.get("spark.es.nodes"))
```